# Android - file download problem - incomplete file

Tags: java, android, file, download

I have checked many code snippets, tried with and without buffer and I can't get to download whole file to SD card. The code I use currently is:

```
    try {
        url = new URL("http://mywebsite.com/directory/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) { }

    String filename = "someKindOfFile.jpg"; // this won't be .jpg in future

    File folder = new File(PATH); // TODO: add checking if folder exist
    if (folder.mkdir()) Log.i("MKDIR", "Folder created");
    else Log.i("MKDIR", "Folder not created");
    File file = new File(folder, filename);

    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
```

This code creates directory on SD card but downloads only 77 bytes of files. What might be the problem?

Comment: how can you knw tht only 77byte is downloaded?

Comment: @chirag-shag 77 bytes is the size of file in DDMS Emulator SD card file explorer

Comment: What is the expected result? Have you tried downloading the same content with a tool like wget or curl to compare against what your code is downloading? What is the contents of the 77 byte file you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that he was writing the `count` variable converted to `byte` datatype instead of the bytes read from the input stream (those should be stored in a temporary `byte[] buffer` via `bis.read(buffer)`)
The proper code block should be:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
int current = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((current = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, current);
}
fos.close();
is.close();
```